# Refused to execute script from 'url' because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch book cover,title and author using openlibrary.org api. But i can't do it.When i click the search this image appears as shown in screenshot.Also i am providing some source code.And i am getting error "Refused to execute script from 'http://ia800609.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/28/items/olcovers121/olcovers121-M.zip&file=1212744-M.jpg&ext=' because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable."
Please provide some suggetion regarding solving the error.Thanks in advance.

```js
function search_google_books() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  var isbn = document.forms[0].isbn;

  if (isbn && isbn.value != '') {
    document.getElementById('thumbnail').innerHTML = '<img src="./loading.gif" />';
    script.src = 'http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/' + isbn.value + '-M.jpg';


    document.body.appendChild(script);
  } else {
    alert('Please input ISBN!');
  }
}

function show_bookcover(booksInfo) {
  var link = '<span class="nolink">No image available...</span>';
  for (i in booksInfo.items) {
    var book = booksInfo.items[i]
    var image = book.volumeInfo.imageLinks;
    if (image && image.thumbnail != undefined) {
      var thumbnail = image.thumbnail.replace('zoom=5', 'zoom=1');
      if (document.location.protocol == 'https:') {
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = thumbnail;
        parser.protocol = 'https:';
        parser.hostname = 'encrypted.google.com';
        thumbnail = parser.href;
      }
      link = '<img src="' + thumbnail + '" />';
      if (book.accessInfo && book.accessInfo.viewability != "NO_PAGES") {
        var preview = book.volumeInfo.previewLink;
        link += '<br />';
      }
    }
    link += '<br />Title: ' + book.volumeInfo.title;
    if (book.volumeInfo.authors.length > 0) {
      link += '<br />Author: ' + book.volumeInfo.authors.join("; ");
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('thumbnail').innerHTML = link;
} <
```

```css
#thumbnail {
  margin: 1em 4em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test for Open Search API: book cover</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="form">
    <form>
      Enter ISBN: <input type="text" size="40" placeholder="ISBN" value="9780415261876" name="isbn" id="isbn" />
      <button onclick="javascript:search_google_books();
            return false;">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="thumbnail"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `script.src = 'http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/' + isbn.value + '-M.jpg'` to do?

Comment: Book cover,title and author name related to that isbn value

Comment: I think what @LeeTaylor ment, is that you are probably using a jpeg binary as the source of a script tag. Which is probably not what you intent to do. Therefore the error is technically correct.. An image/jpeg is not executable by the script parser.

Comment: A script can only be text, such as your javascript above. You're trying to use an image for a script. This will not work. Again, what are you **wanting** to do?

Comment: The URL is pointing to a picture, not a script. You got the URL wrong. Looks like the problem is a typo.

Comment: @Christiaan Nieuwlaat can't understand your comment, please explain more about LeeTaylor's comment.

Comment: The url you are pointing to in the code returns a 302 redirect to another URL of a jpeg image. It's not the URL pointing to a javascript file. The script engine in the browser will only parse and execute scripts that are supported (like js). Instead it gets a file of image/JPEG (which isn't a script format). If you want to fetch the image, don't use a script element, but use a img element :-)

Comment: @LeeTaylor i want to fetch image from openlibrary.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just want to fetch the associated book cover image, a few minor modifications in your code would be enough:

```js
function search_google_books() {
  var isbn = document.forms[0].isbn;

  if (isbn && isbn.value != '') {
    document.getElementById('thumbnail').innerHTML = '<img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/' + isbn.value + '-M.jpg" />';

  } else {
    alert('Please input ISBN!');
  }
}
```

```css
#thumbnail {
  margin: 1em 4em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test for Open Search API: book cover</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="form">
    <form>
      Enter ISBN: <input type="text" size="40" placeholder="ISBN" value="9780415261876" name="isbn" id="isbn" />
      <button onclick="javascript:search_google_books();
            return false;">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="thumbnail"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor i upvoted it, a pop up shows that "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."